# List of voice commands which trigger heart rate check

Tags: android, wear-os, voice-recognition, google-now, google-fit

What is the list of all existing voice commands which create an intent with `vnd.google.fitness.VIEW` action and `vnd.google.fitness.data_type/com.google.heart_rate.bpm` mime type?

[The documentation shows](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html) only two of them:

1. "OK Google, what’s my heart rate?"
2. "OK Google, what’s my bpm?"

but I've discovered more, for example:

3. "OK Google, check my pulse."

Comment: I managed to read *"List of voice commands which trigger heart attack"*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation also states those are "Example Phrases".
The reason for that it's because such a list does not exist.

Voice commands on those type of platforms (Google Now, Siri) use quite more advanced algorithms to recognize what a person wants, and not just recognize the actual words. That is called "natural voice".

That all means, that a "List of voice commands" does not exist as the platform is capable of adapt and interpret variations.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. However, apart from the syntax, a list of basic keywords which are semantically related to this particular intent (bpm, heart, pulse, check, rate etc.) should be defined somewhere, right?

Comment: I agree, but I believe that those will be part of the intellectual property of the natural voice recognition system and won't be part of public domain documentation.